# Append value into list inside json file

Tags: python, json

I need to append template in place 'here' and I have no idea how to do that. 
There's how json look like:

```
{
    "1st_thing":
    [{"1st":"1stvalue"},{"2nd":"2ndvalue"}, /*here*/],
    "2nd_thing":
    [{"xx":"XXvalue"},{"yy":"YYvalue"},/*here*/]
}
```

I've tried this and it only do this temporary but I need to save it in 'tokens.json'

```
with open("tokens.json") as f:
    new = json.load(f)
    new['captcha_tokens'].append(template)
```

Comment: Save the `new` variable to a (new) JSON file with `json.dump()`.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dump` to write to a new file:

```
json.dump(new, open("tokens_new.json", "w"))
```

Or if you want to prettify a bit:

```
json.dump(new, open("tokens_new.json", "w"), ensure_ascii=True, indent=4)
```

Then you can replace tokens.json with `shutil`:

```
import shutil
shutil.copy("tokens_new.json", "tokens.json")
```